# CSS3 background-size - can I guarantee coverage?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a website that uses an image as its background over the entire page. In order to do this, I am using the new CSS3 spec "background-size", which is set to "cover".

```
background-image: url(/images/House-Remodel-Ideas2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Generally speaking this works well, but I noticed that if the window starts to get too narrow (and this a fairly wide image, so even 1024x768 is "too narrow") then the image stop filling the page and instead I see the background color of the page.

This kind of destroys the look of the page. While I suppose I can get creative about both the size of the image and the overall design of the page, it would be nice if this worked as expected. I'm OK with the image spilling over or getting clipped, but I'm not OK with it being too small and leaving the page background showing.

Is there a way to set this up so that doesn't happen?

An example was requested, so... here is the image I'm using:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVUrt.jpg

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(house.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I put an obnoxious red background behind the image to demonstrate the problem. If it is working properly, you should NOT see the red. So run the above, and then resize the browser so that it is very thin, and tall. You will see lots of red under the picture. THAT's the problem.

As an update, upon more testing, removing the DOCTYPE seems to fix the problem. I am not smart enough to tell you why. :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I wasn't familiar with background-size. I found this site very informative: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of what you're seeing? I can't seem to replicate this in Chrome.

Comment: @SteveAdams Perhaps you could post your own link to a test case showing it working fine for you.

Comment: Hmmm... ok, so I just learned something, and think I found the answer in the process. I was in the process of building a vanilla example to show you the problem, and reproduced it easily, even in Chrome. But I wanted to make the source code as small as possible to post here. So I started to remove things one at a time. Nothing changed until decided to delete the "<!DOCTYPE html>" from the top of the file, and boom! The problem went away! Since then I tried several flavors of DocType (strict, transitional) but it seems like having ANY DocType causes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't implemented a css-only way to do this, but I did use the backstretch jQuery plugin once, and it worked across the board. http://srobbin.com/blog/easy-full-screen-background-images-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you. While it doesn't actually answer the exact (CSS) question, it does keep me working for now. My thinking is that CSS isn't going to do it for now.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe some day the vendors will all agree on a standard and we won't have to even worry about stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `height` or `min-height` of the `html`:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/igLMC.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```