# How to cover the background with an image regardless of size of the background and image?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get a background image to cover the entire window but am having trouble getting it to behave the way I'd want.

I currently have

```
'background-size': 'cover'
```

However, I find when shrink the width, the image tiles.

[image]

So I changed it to:

```
'background-size': 'cover',
'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
```

But now, just white space appears below the image.

[image]

So then I tried

```
'background-size': 'fill',
'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
```

However, now when the image is smaller than the window, it doesn't expand to fill the window.

What is the best solution so that the image covers the entire screen, doesn't tile, and doesn't have white space regarldess of the size of the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958697/css3-background-size-cover-doesnt-make-image-cover-vertically?rq=1

Comment: you have to give him height: 100vh

Comment: are you really using these single quotes and commas in CSS? That won't work... Or is that in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly set the size of the background to cover the entire viewport by setting the height to `100vh` (i.e. 100% of the available viewport height). This coupled with `background-size: cover` should handle your scenario :

```
body {
    background: url('{background-url}');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**Example**

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/begeru/edit?css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to give him

```
height: 100vh
```

```css
body{margin: 0px;}
div{
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/400/600);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html {
  background: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Should work with Safari 3+, Chrome Whatever+, IE 9+, Opera 10+, Firefox 3.6+

Source: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)